# Show validation error for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two model with following association

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, reject_if: proc { |attributes| (attributes['user_id'].blank? || attributes['numbers'].blank?) }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :article

before_save :mytest

  def mytest
    self.article.phase != Category::STD["author"] && self.article.user_id == self.user_id
  end
end
```

Now if the validation of mytest method fails then article does not save. This is expected behavior. But this does not give any error message. I want to show an error message "You are not admin" if mytest method fails. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the error to the object. Either to the base object of one of the attributes.

```
def mytest
  valid = self.article.phase != Category::STD["author"] &&
    self.article.user_id == self.user_id
  self.errors.add(:base, 'You are not admin')
  # or self.errors.add(:attribute_name, 'You are not admin')
end
```

then in the view you can check if an error is present on base and render it

EDIT: More code as requested

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  validate :mytest

  private

  def mytest
    valid = self.article.phase != Category::STD["author"] &&
      self.article.user_id == self.user_id
    self.article.errors.add(:base, 'Not admin user error')
  end
end

class ArticleController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
      redirect_to some_path, notice: 'success message'
    else
      if @article.errors.messages[:base].include? 'Not admin user error'
        flash.now[:alert] = 'You are not admin'
      end
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if you still have issues understanding what you need to do

Comment: The problem is, object self is nil. So I get this error `undefined method phase for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Undefined method what?

Comment: undefined method phase

Comment: So it's saying article is nil. Are you sure you are passing the parans correctly from the form. i.e. The strong params are setup correctly. The console will say unpermitted params: :param1 :param2 etc if they aren't included.

Comment: You should also check that article exists in the valid = condition. i.e. self.article.present? && other conditions

Comment: yes I am doing it right. But object self is nill, so article is also nil.

Comment: Are you sure self is nil. If so the undefined method should be article not phase. Can you use pry to check what self is

Answer (score 0):

You gotta manually add the error since you are using a custom validation method.

```
errors.add(:mystest, :invalid) if self.article.phase != Category::STD["author"] ...
```

and you gotta change from before_save to validates

```
validates :mytest
```

This will execute your method `mytest` as a validation method and it will insert an error in the object in case something is wrong.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` should get the child errors and return it for you when you access the errors at the main object.

Comment: could you please show the complete code? I get error

Comment: This code is just the idea. Not sure it works as it should.